# android mysql listview

Tags: android, mysql

I have stuck at a point, I have a simple mysql database having table of name and address,
I am able to get the json array for the same but m not able to populate listview. Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to populate listview"? What have you done?

Comment: i have able to get list view  for static content  , like this http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html. but I want a dynamic content , in frustration i have deleted thee current files.. can u guide pl , inlcuding layout files to

Comment: see this example http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html

Comment: m getting json array from php and mysqwl, if i have 10 records of name and addres then m getting array of 10, but m not able to proceed furthere

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already know how to use the `ListView` control and using adpater, then you need to create a custom adapter, by extending `BaseAdapter`, and then overriding the `getCount()`, `getItem()`, `getItemId()`, and `getView()` methods.

For example your BaseAdapter implementation might take a `JSONArray` and might be something like this...

```
public class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private JSONArray array = null;
   public JSONAdapter(JSONArray data) {
      this.array=data;
   }
   public int getCount() {
      return array.length();
   }
   public Object getItem(int position) {
      return array.get(position);
   }
   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
   }
   public View getView(int position, View currentView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // get the current item from the json array
      JSONObject o = getItem(position);

      // create a new view
      View v;
      if (convertView == null || newItemView) {
         v = inflater.inflate(YOUR_ITEM_LAYOUT_VIEW_ID, parent, false);
      } else {
         v = convertView;
      }

      // populate the view
      // use v.findViewById() to locate your layout items and then
      // set a value from the JSONObject that you obtained above

      return view;
   }
}
```

The above code may not compile directly (and doesn't contain any error checking), since I just typed it inline here... but hopefully it gives you an idea of how you'd create a `ListAdapter` that can accept a `JSONArray`.